# Loading a html page from other page and prefilling the values in textboxes in the catered pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got stuck in a problem.

Problem is:

I have to load a html page(say test.html) on click of a button from some page(say home page).

Now test.html contains some input boxes which I need to prefill while loading the test.html.

Content of **home page**

```
<body>

<h1> Page 1 </h1>

<div id="topBar">
    <a href ="#" id="load_home" onclick="load_home()"> HOME </a>
</div>
<div id ="content">        
</div>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="test.html" ></object>';
                document.getElementsByClassName('monday_spends').setAttribute("value", "yolo");
});
</script>
```

**test.html contains**

```
<table class="ss-moneyDetails">
      <tr>
        <th>Details:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td><i class="ss-iconRupee">&#8377;</i><span>
        <input class="monday_spends" type="text" value="" name="monday_spends"/>20,000</span></td>
      </tr>
</table
```

I need to prefill the value of  `<input class="monday_spends" type="text" value="" name="monday_spends"/>` while loading the page test.html from home.html.

**NOTE** : I am also trying to do this by calling a **ajax request which will cater the html page and prefilling the data. Is it possible** ?
Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need javascript for this, just alter the URL

Comment: Something like test.html&money_spends=20000

Comment: I didn't get you. can you please explain?

Comment: @Roberrrt: This I don't want to do as If will change my mind to load the page in other tab then this doesn't seems good.

Comment: If you click on the button, you wish to populate the values correct? You can  enter parameters inside the url to do so, but the values will still be empty when you enter the blank URL.

Comment: @Roberrrt: I was telling about your first comment : You don't need javascript for this, just alter the URL

Comment: Oh, I see, well let me mock up the entire solution in an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert JavaScript inside an `<object>` which you embed on your webpage. 
However, you can rely on constructing the URL of the page you're embedding, to pre-fill certain inputs. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var money = 500;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = 
    '<object type="text/html" data="test.html?money_spend='+ money +'" ></object>';
});
```

Comment: the class money_spend or id is enclosed in a parent div. I don't think this will be able to prefill the data in the specified tag.

Comment: The URL doesn't look for the class, but rather the `name` attribute of the input element. Which is also `money_spend`

Comment: And if you'd use the `id` of the inputs in conjunction with the `name` ?

Comment: value of id and name is same

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using this process.

I have created an input tag of hidden type and embed it in form tag in `test.html`.

```
<form action="file:///Users/XYZ/Desktop/abc/home.html" method="GET">
   <input type="hidden" id="foo" name="foo">
   <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

and in script section I have assigned a value to the `foo` as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = {};
    data.name = "Mukul";
    data.place = "gurgaon";
    var data1 = JSON.stringify(data);
    $("#foo").val(data1);
});
```

Now in `home.html`

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  processForm();
  function processForm()
  {
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");  
    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
    data = unescape(temp[1]);
    console.log("i got the data from test.html");
    $("#tag1").val(data);

  }
  $()
</script>
```

I have retrieved the value from the url and appended it to the desired value.